# tinytex:::is_tinytex() returns true, but I still cannot knit to a PDF from rmarkdown

Tags: r-markdown, tinytex

When I knit to pdf, I get a pop up that says "The code execution cannot proceed because luatex.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem." I click OK, then I get this output:

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/W32TeX)
>   (preloaded format=pdflatex)  restricted \write18 enabled. Running the
>   command
>   C:\Users\Ryan.M.Allen\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\fmtutil-user.exe
>
> I can't find the format file `pdflatex.fmt'!
>
> kpathsea: Running mktexfmt pdflatex.fmt
>
> The command name is
>   C:\Users\Ryan.M.Allen\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\mktexfmt I was
>   unable to find any missing LaTeX packages from the error log
>   BA_LunchLearn.log. ! Running the command
>   C:\Users\Ryan.M.Allen\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\fmtutil-user.exe
>
> ! kpathsea: Running mktexfmt pdflatex.fmt
>
> ! The command name is
>   C:\Users\Ryan.M.Allen\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\mktexfmt
>
> Error: LaTeX failed to compile BA_LunchLearn.tex. See
>   https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See
>   BA_LunchLearn.log for more info. In addition: Warning message: package
>   'corrplot' was built under R version 3.6.3  Execution halted

I have tried uninstalling tinytex and reinstalling it and then restarting Rstudio each time. I also get the output of `TRUE` when I run the command `tinytex:::is_tinytex()`. So I think it is on my machine but the pdf knit does not work.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/61777248/559676

Comment: Thank you. I will follow that issue to see when it will be back up and running.